# Firefox button text color

Tags: firefox

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Cinnamon 2.6.12 and Firefox 53.0.3. The default button color in Firefox (for things like "OK", "Cancel", etc) is white, but the background is also white, so it is almost unreadable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firefox on Ubuntu has a custom addon/extension for theming the UI. What you have to understand is that Firefox on Linux is an amalgamation of different UI toolkits, where some components are "native GTK+" and have the appearance dictated by the underlying GTK engine (which Cinnamon would drive the appearance of), and other components are XUL or the new UI based ("Australis").

If you remove/disable the Ubuntu theme for Firefox, you might get better results: Firefox will revert to its default theme, which might be more compatible with the color palette of the GTK widgets.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried installing new themes in firefox, and adjusting the system theme in cinnamon, but the default color is style white on very light gray.

Comment: Generally you have to tweak GTK3 colours, which may have the side effect of making other controls orange.... Firefox lost the plot on this one.